# See disk management info with c#

Tags: c#, volume, disk, hard-drive

When I open `Disk Management` (right click My Computer->Manage) I see:
[image]

**How can I know that path `F:\` belongs to Disk5?**  In other words I will like to know what disks are available with C#.

The reason why I need to know that is because I have a usb mas storage device that is encrypted and I need to pass the parameter `\Device\Harddisk5` to [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) along with the password in order to mount the encrypted device with code.

### Edit

I know how to look the drives info. I just dont konw how to know that Drive 1 belongs to disk 0 for instance. In other words I am having trouble figuring out the **Disk Number**. I am looking to implement:

```
public string GetDiskNumber(char letter)
{
   // implenetation
   return Disk5;
}
```

where I will call that as:

```
GetDiskNumber('F');
```

Comment: I assume you are doing this via C# Code..? have you looked at using `WMI`

Comment: WMI is what I would use to get this information as well, check out these classes Win32_DiskDrive and Win32_DiskPartition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use WMI to retrieve that information

```
System.Management.ManagementObject("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=" & DriveLetter & ":")
```

See more at [Win32_LogicalDisk class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I hope it helps. By the way there is PInvoke too [GetVolumeInformation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getvolumeinformation).

If you need 'PHYSICALDRIVE0' you should use [Win32_PhysicalMedia class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the class [Win32_DiskDrivePhysicalMedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) glue both.

An exemple of your need in C#

```
public string GetDiskNumber(string letter)
{
    var ret = "0";
    var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");
    var query = new ObjectQuery("Associators of {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" +     letter + ":'} WHERE ResultRole=Antecedent");
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    var queryCollection = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
        ret = m["Name"].ToString().Replace("Disk #", "")[0].ToString();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: That gives a lot of info. when I try `System.Management.ManagementObject("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=c:")` for instance how can I know its drive 0?

Comment: If you need the name like 'PHYSICALDRIVE0' you should Win32_PhysicalMedia class.

Answer (score 2):

Have made a method for you gets drive letter and its number in a dictionary;

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetDrives()
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach ( var drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher( "Select * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition" ).Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().ToList() )
            {
                var driveLetter = Regex.Match( (string)drive[ "Dependent" ], @"DeviceID=""(.*)""" ).Groups[ 1 ].Value;
                var driveNumber = Regex.Match( (string)drive[ "Antecedent" ], @"Disk #(\d*)," ).Groups[ 1 ].Value;
                result.Add( driveLetter, driveNumber );
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: That does not tell me what drive number drive F is :(

Comment: Works too I tried other answer first. +1 for great help! thanks so much!